# Sort While Preserving Locations of Groups

Tags: r, performance, sorting, dplyr, grouping

Suppose I have a `tibble` like `tb_1` here

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  Grp     Srt
  <chr> <int>
1 A        10
2 B         4
3 B         7
4 A         5
5 A         1
6 A         3
7 B         2
```

which I have reproduced below:

```
tb_1 <- structure(
  list(
    Grp = c("A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B"),
    Srt = c(10L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 2L)
  ),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
  row.names = c(NA, -7L)
)
```

**I would like a performant function `arrange_groups()` in the [style](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/arrange.html) of [`dplyr`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/index.html); which will sort (by given variables) the observations within each existing group, while preserving the locations *where* that group is distributed.**

```
library(dplyr)


tb_2 <- tb_1 %>%

  # Group by 'Grp'.
  group_by(Grp) %>%

  # Sort by 'Srt' WITHIN each group.
  arrange_groups(Srt)
```

In the resulting `tb_2`, the 4 observations from the `"A"` group should remain distributed among the `1`st, `4`th, `5`th, and `6`th rows; after they have been sorted by `Srt` among themselves. Likewise, the 3 observations from the `"B"` group should remain distributed among the `2`nd, `3`rd, and `7`th rows.

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
# Groups:   Grp [2]
  Grp     Srt
  <chr> <int>
1 A         1
2 B         2
3 B         4
4 A         3
5 A         5
6 A        10
7 B         7
```

I have reproduced `tb_2` below:

```
tb_2 <- structure(
  list(
    Grp = c("A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B"),
    Srt = c(1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 10L, 7L)
  ),
  class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
  row.names = c(NA, -7L),
  groups = structure(
    list(
      Grp = c("A", "B"),
      .rows = structure(
        list(
          c(1L, 4L, 5L, 6L),
          c(2L, 3L, 7L)
        ),
        ptype = integer(0),
        class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", "list")
      )
    ),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
    row.names = c(NA, -2L),
    .drop = TRUE
  )
)
```

---

## Update

While I was able to [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70760308) my own question, I am leaving the floor open for other solutions. I am curious to see what [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70760281/sort-while-preserving-locations-of-groups/70760308#comment125093549_70760308) exist, especially those that are more performant, more creative, or work with different ecosystems like [**`data.table`**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table).

### Toward Optimization

Further solutions should ideally

1. avoid recalculating `order(Srt_1, Srt_2, ...)` for every column in `df`;
2. be no slower than [existing suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70761268) in **`data.table`**.

Answer (score 4):

## Solutions

Within the [**`tidyverse`**](https://www.tidyverse.org), that goal can be accomplished by either a simple workflow or (among others) the following two functions.

### Workflow

You could simply ignore `arrange_groups()` and instead implement a [**`dplyr`**](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org) workflow with `mutate()`, since operations (like `order()`) will be applied within groups anyway.

```
library(dplyr)

tb_1 %>%
    group_by(Grp) %>%

    # Arbitrary sorting variables go HERE:
    mutate(across(everything(), ~.[order(Srt)]))
    #                                    ^^^
```

### Reordering Function

This `arrange_groups_1()` function sorts first by existing groups, and then by the variables given in `...`. With the data thus sorted within its groups, `arrange_groups_1()` then maps those groups back to their original locations.

```
arrange_groups_1 <- function(.data, ...) {
  # Arrange into group "regions", and sort within each region; then...
  dplyr::arrange(.data = .data, ... = ..., .by_group = TRUE)[
    # ...map the results back to the original structure.
    order(order(dplyr::group_indices(.data = .data))),
  ]
}
```

It is compatible with **`dplyr`**:

```
library(dplyr)

tb_1 %>%
    group_by(Grp) %>%
    arrange_groups_1(Srt)
```

### Mutating Function

Less clever but more straightforward than `arrange_groups_1()`, the `arrange_groups_2()` solution simply implements the workflow in functional form.

```
arrange_groups_2 <- function(.data, ...) {
  # Capture the symbols for the sorting variables.
  dots <- dplyr::enquos(...)
  
  dplyr::mutate(
    .data = .data,
    dplyr::across(
      # Sort across the entire dataset.
      .cols = dplyr::everything(),

      # Sort each group "in place"; by variables captured from the proper scope.
      .fns = ~.[order(!!!dots)]
    )
  )
}
```

It too is compatible with **`dplyr`**:

```
library(dplyr)

tb_1 %>%
    group_by(Grp) %>%
    arrange_groups_2(Srt)
```

## Result

Given a `tb_1` like yours, all of these solutions will yield the desired result:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
# Groups:   Grp [2]
  Grp     Srt
  <chr> <int>
1 A         1
2 B         2
3 B         4
4 A         3
5 A         5
6 A        10
7 B         7
```

## Performance

On large datasets, the disparity in performance might become significant. Given a `df` with 1 million observations and several variables for grouping (`Grp_*`) and sorting (`Srt_*`)

```
set.seed(0)

df <- data.frame(
    Record_ID = 1:1000000,

    Grp_1 = sample(x = letters[ 1:6 ] , size = 1000000, replace = TRUE ),
    Grp_2 = sample(x = letters[ 7:12] , size = 1000000, replace = TRUE ),
    Grp_3 = sample(x = letters[13:18] , size = 1000000, replace = TRUE ),
    Grp_4 = sample(x = letters[19:26] , size = 1000000, replace = TRUE ),
    
    Srt_1 = sample(x =       1:1000000, size = 1000000, replace = FALSE),
    Srt_2 = sample(x = 1000001:2000000, size = 1000000, replace = FALSE),
    Srt_3 = sample(x = 2000001:3000000, size = 1000000, replace = FALSE),
    Srt_4 = sample(x = 3000001:4000000, size = 1000000, replace = FALSE)
)
```

here are calculated the relative performances of each solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(microbenchmark)

performances <- list(
  one_var = microbenchmark(
    arrange_groups_1 = df %>%
      group_by(Grp_1) %>%
      arrange_groups_1(Srt_1), 
    arrange_groups_2 = df %>%
      group_by(Grp_1) %>%
      arrange_groups_2(Srt_1), 
    workflow = df %>%
      group_by(Grp_1) %>%
      mutate(across(everything(), ~.[order(Srt_1)])),
    times = 50
  ),
  two_vars = microbenchmark(
    arrange_groups_1 = df %>%
      group_by(Grp_1, Grp_2) %>%
      arrange_groups_1(Srt_1, Srt_2),
    arrange_groups_2 = df %>%
      group_by(Grp_1, Grp_2) %>%
      arrange_groups_2(Srt_1, Srt_2),
    workflow = df %>%
      group_by(Grp_1, Grp_2) %>%
      mutate(across(everything(), ~.[order(Srt_1, Srt_2)])),
    times = 50
  ),
  three_vars = microbenchmark(
    arrange_groups_1 = df %>%
      group_by(Grp_1, Grp_2, Grp_3) %>%
      arrange_groups_1(Srt_1, Srt_2, Srt_3),
    arrange_groups_2 = df %>%
      group_by(Grp_1, Grp_2, Grp_3) %>%
      arrange_groups_2(Srt_1, Srt_2, Srt_3),
    workflow = df %>%
      group_by(Grp_1, Grp_2, Grp_3) %>%
      mutate(across(everything(), ~.[order(Srt_1, Srt_2, Srt_3)])),
    times = 50
  ),
  four_vars = microbenchmark(
    arrange_groups_1 = df %>%
      group_by(Grp_1, Grp_2, Grp_3, Grp_4) %>%
      arrange_groups_1(Srt_1, Srt_2, Srt_3, Srt_4),
    arrange_groups_2 = df %>%
      group_by(Grp_1, Grp_2, Grp_3, Grp_4) %>%
      arrange_groups_2(Srt_1, Srt_2, Srt_3, Srt_4),
    workflow = df %>%
      group_by(Grp_1, Grp_2, Grp_3, Grp_4) %>%
      mutate(across(everything(), ~.[order(Srt_1, Srt_2, Srt_3, Srt_4)])),
    times = 50
  )
)
```

Clearly `arrange_groups_1()` is outclassed. I suspect `arrange_groups_2()` can hold its own against the workflow, and remain within sight of the latter while offering more ergonomic usage. However, this suspicion should be verified on other (and better) machines for larger sets of grouping and sorting variables.

```
#> performances

$one_var
Unit: milliseconds
             expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 arrange_groups_1 2066.4674 2155.8859 2231.3547 2199.7442 2283.5782 2565.0542    50
 arrange_groups_2  352.3775  385.1829  435.2595  444.8746  464.1493  607.0927    50
         workflow  337.2756  391.0174  428.9049  435.8385  454.7347  546.4498    50

$two_vars
Unit: milliseconds
             expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 arrange_groups_1 3580.5395 3688.1506 3842.2048 3799.5430 3979.9716 4317.7100    50
 arrange_groups_2  230.1166  239.9141  265.0786  249.3640  287.1006  359.1822    50
         workflow  221.6627  234.2732  256.6200  243.3707  281.2269  365.9102    50

$three_vars
Unit: milliseconds
             expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 arrange_groups_1 5113.6341 5340.5483 5441.3399 5443.5068 5535.0578 5946.6958    50
 arrange_groups_2  261.9329  274.1785  295.6854  282.4638  323.5710  412.0139    50
         workflow  224.8709  236.9958  263.2440  252.6042  292.7043  339.6351    50

$four_vars
Unit: milliseconds
             expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
 arrange_groups_1 6810.3864 7035.7077 7237.6941 7156.7051 7314.4667 8051.8558    50
 arrange_groups_2  581.9000  603.7822  640.8977  626.4116  672.6488  859.8239    50
         workflow  349.7786  361.6454  391.7517  375.1532  429.3643  485.9227    50
```

---

## Update

### Hybrid Function

Inspired by [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/u/3732271)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70761268), here is a function that integrates the power of [**`data.table`**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table)...

```
arrange_groups_3 <- function(.data, ...) {
  # Name the variables for grouping, and their complement in '.data'.
  group_vars <- dplyr::group_vars(.data)
  other_vars <- setdiff(names(.data), group_vars)

  # For proper scoping, generate here the expression for sorting.
  sort_expr <- substitute(order(...))
  
  dplyr::as_tibble(data.table::as.data.table(.data)[,
    (other_vars) := lapply(
      # Sort each column, using an index...
      .SD, \(x, i) x[i],

      # ...which we need calculate only once.
      i = eval(sort_expr)
    ),
    group_vars
  ])
}
```

...with the ergonomics of **`dplyr`**.

```
library(dplyr)

tb_1 %>%
    group_by(Grp) %>%
    arrange_groups_3(Srt)
```

However, my implementation **drops the original grouping** in `.data`, so it's still a **work in progress**.

### Fast Mutate

This rather fast implementation was inspired by [@Henrik](https://stackoverflow.com/u/1851712)'s [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70760281/sort-while-preserving-locations-of-groups/70760308#comment125095698_70760308) to use [**`dtplyr`**](https://dtplyr.tidyverse.org), a **`data.table`** backend for **`dplyr`**.

```
arrange_groups_4 <- function(.data, ...) {
  # Capture the symbols for the sorting and grouping variables.
  sort_syms <- dplyr::enquos(...)
  group_syms <- dplyr::groups(.data)
  
  .data |>

    # Use a "data.table" backend.
    dtplyr::lazy_dt() |>

    # Preserve the grouping.
    dplyr::group_by(!!!group_syms) |>

    # Perform the sorting.
    dplyr::mutate(
      dplyr::across(
        # Sort across the entire dataset.
        .cols = dplyr::everything(),
        
        # Sort each group "in place": subscript using the index...
        .fns = `[`,
        
        # ...generated when ordering by the sorting variables.
        i = order(!!!sort_syms)
      )
    )
}
```

Although I have yet to test it for more than `4` grouping and sorting variables, it *seems* to complete in linear time:

```
$one_var
Unit: milliseconds
             expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
 arrange_groups_4 30.738 31.8028 46.81692 37.6586 59.8274 95.4703    50

$two_vars
Unit: milliseconds
             expr     min      lq     mean  median      uq    max neval
 arrange_groups_4 41.4364 41.9118 52.91332 46.4306 66.1674 80.171    50

$three_vars
Unit: milliseconds
             expr     min      lq     mean  median     uq      max neval
 arrange_groups_4 47.8605 48.6225 62.06675 51.9562 71.487 237.0102    50

$four_vars
Unit: milliseconds
             expr    min      lq     mean   median      uq      max neval
 arrange_groups_4 67.306 69.1426 78.68869 73.81695 88.7874 108.2624    50
```

Comment: Perhaps, `data.table` option would be faster (not checked); `library(data.table);grpnms <- grep("Grp", names(tb_1), value = TRUE);othernms <- setdiff(names(tb_1), grpnms);setDT(tb_1)[, (othernms) := lapply(.SD, \(x) x[order(Srt)]), grpnms]`

Comment: @akrun Yes, I suspect it would be.  Feel free to supplement this solution with your own!  However, the question *was* looking for something that ergonomically integrates with the **`dplyr`** workflow.

Comment: then, it is okay as I leave it as comment as you are looking for tidyverse option.

Comment: @akrun Could a function `arrange_groups_3(.data, ...)` be achieved with **`data.table`** under the hood?

Comment: It is possible.  Can you please add the results of the benchmark in case somebody wants to test a new function without running all the functions. thanks

Comment: @akrun Working on it; it's just taking a while to run.  The preliminary benchmarks suggest `arrange_groups_2()` is at least an order of magnitude than `arrange_groups_1()`, which sadly was my favorite for its creativity. The workflow is slightly faster than `arrange_groups_2()`, but I think that's just due to the overhead of calling a function and injecting `...` from the proper scope.

Comment: @akrun The benchmark results are posted! My machine is somewhat inconsistent, so I'd advise verifying a handful of those on your own.

Comment: There is a slight improvement in efficiency I checked with `four_vars` for 'workflow' i.e. the workflow `system.time` `# user  system elapsed 
#  0.552   0.013   0.564` and data.table is `# user  system elapsed 
#  0.348   0.012   0.360`. I didn't use the microbenchmark as i am doing the `:=` in data.table

Comment: @akrun Very neat!  When you get the chance, would you kindly post that as an answer?

Comment: @Greg Because your write "power of `data.table` with the ergonomics of `dplyr`", are you familiar with [`dtplyr`](https://github.com/tidyverse/dtplyr)?

Comment: @Henrik I have yet to explore it **`dtplyr`**, though I am familiar with its premise.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another `dplyr` solution relying on a join preserving the row order. (The `id` column can of course be dropped as a last step, and the temporary objects aren't necessary to create separately, but the method is nice and clear with this presentation.)

```
group_order = tb_1 %>%
  select(Grp) %>%
  group_by(Grp) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number())

row_order = tb_1 %>%
  arrange(Srt) %>%
  group_by(Grp) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number())

result = group_order %>% left_join(row_order, by = c("Grp", "id"))
result
# # A tibble: 7 × 3
# # Groups:   Grp [2]
#   Grp      id   Srt
#   <chr> <int> <int>
# 1 A         1     1
# 2 B         1     2
# 3 B         2     4
# 4 A         2     3
# 5 A         3     5
# 6 A         4    10
# 7 B         3     7
```

---

Benchmarking, this is better than `arrange_groups_1` but otherwise not great:

```
four_vars = microbenchmark(
     arrange_groups_2 = df %>%
      group_by(Grp_1, Grp_2, Grp_3, Grp_4) %>%
      arrange_groups_2(Srt_1, Srt_2, Srt_3, Srt_4),
    workflow = df %>%
      group_by(Grp_1, Grp_2, Grp_3, Grp_4) %>%
      mutate(across(everything(), ~.[order(Srt_1, Srt_2, Srt_3, Srt_4)])),
    join = {
      df %>%
        group_by(Grp_1, Grp_2, Grp_3, Grp_4) %>%
        mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
        left_join(
          df %>%
            arrange(Srt_1, Srt_2, Srt_3, Srt_4) %>%
            group_by(Grp_1, Grp_2, Grp_3, Grp_4) %>%
            mutate(id = row_number()),
          by = c("Grp_1", "Grp_2", "Grp_3", "Grp_4", "id")
        )
    },
    times = 10
  )
four_vars
# Unit: milliseconds
#              expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#  arrange_groups_2 356.7114 366.2305 393.7209 377.6245 389.1009 537.6800    10
#          workflow 242.6982 245.5079 252.8441 252.3410 257.7656 267.5277    10
#              join 366.6957 400.1438 438.5274 443.0696 477.5481 505.2293    10
```

Comment: Thanks Gregor! I leveraged the same mapping principle [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70760308) with `arrange_groups_1()`, though I did so implicitly with `[order(order(group_indices())), ]`.  Could you benchmark your solution, by any chance?  I'm trying with @akrun to find the function with optimal performance that integrates with **`dplyr`**.

Comment: @Greg I saw your update function.  Running that gives `user  system elapsed 
  0.508   0.022   0.528` compared to `#user  system elapsed 
  0.675   0.005   0.678` for `arrange_groups_2`

Comment: @akrun Very good to know! But I just realized that this new `arrange_groups_3()` fails to preserve the original grouping in `.data`, so I'll have to rework something...and that will likely hurt the efficiency.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @Greg those attributes are only in the tibble.  Once it is converted to data.table, it may be removed.  I guess there may be some options in dtplyr.  Not checked

Comment: Benchmarks added. It's an okay approach, but not competitive.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you for appending the benchmark!

Answer (score 1):

The question asked about `dplyr`.  Here, is an attempt with `data.table` as this also involves efficiency.  Benchmarks with OP's big dataset 'df' are below

```
library(data.table)
system.time({

df %>%
      group_by(Grp_1, Grp_2, Grp_3, Grp_4) %>%
      mutate(across(everything(), ~.[order(Srt_1, Srt_2, Srt_3, Srt_4)]))
})
# user  system elapsed 
#  0.552   0.013   0.564 


system.time({

grpnms <- grep("Grp", names(df), value = TRUE)
othernms <- setdiff(names(df), grpnms)
setDT(df)[, (othernms) := lapply(.SD, \(x) 
         x[order(Srt_1, Srt_2, Srt_3, Srt_4)]), grpnms]


})
#  user  system elapsed 
#  0.348   0.012   0.360
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun!  Any idea how to convert this into a function of the form `arrange_groups_3(.data, ...)`? I tried, but I'm having trouble getting `...` to evaluate in the right scope, namely as a data variable.

Comment: @Greg The `arrange_group` functions you showed are applying the order after grouping in the dplyr.  In the data.table code, I am doing the grouping within data.table.  So, I am not sure whether the functionality you desired is to mix dplyr/data.table.  It may be better to use the grouping/etc in data.table syntax and apply the function as `arrange_group_3(.data, .grp_cols, ...)` where the grp_cols are passed as string column names and the `...` for the rest or the 'Srt' column (or even it can be constructed within the function itself)

Comment: I just realized something: aren't we recalculating `order(Srt_1, Srt_2, Srt_3, Srt_4)` for **each and every column** we're sorting?  Do you think there's a way in **`dtplyr`** that we could do the calculation only once?

Comment: @Greg I think you may need `do.call` with order as in `arrange_groups_3 <- function(.data, .grp_cols, .srt_cols) {
  setDT(.data)  
 
  .data[, (.srt_cols) := lapply(.SD, \(x) x[do.call(order, .SD[, .srt_cols, with = FALSE])]), by = .grp_cols][]

}` and then I used `system.time({
   arrange_groups_3(df, c("Grp_1", "Grp_2", "Grp_3", "Grp_4"), c("Srt_1", "Srt_2", "Srt_3", "Srt_4"))
   })`

Comment: But doesn't this recalculate `order()` on `.srt_cols` every time the anonymous function `\(x)` is called?

Comment: @Greg yes, it does.  But still I found it to be faster than the `arrange_groups_2` function

Comment: @Greg To prevent that, I would add a step before the assignment step to get the order by group and use that in the assignment step so that we don't need recalculation

Comment: Why not something like `lapply(.SD, \(x, i) x[i], i = order(Srt_1, ...))`?  I did that in my hybrid solution, but that's not yet a finished product.  I tried something similar in a variation on `arrange_groups_2()`, but while the whole `mutate(across(everything(), .fns = \(x, i) x[i], i = order(...)))` format works with **`dplyr`**, for some reason it doesn't translate to **`dtplyr`**.

Comment: @Greg Yes, you may try with `do.call(order, list(...))